# Where can I find documentation on functions available in the Ruby Shoe GUI Toolkit?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, api, documentation, shoes

Is there any documentation that discribes all the available functions and objects in shoe?

update: 2008.01.21
I am looking for a list of all the methods that can be called against an animate object.

For example I only figured out how to pause an animation using the toggle() method by reading source code from the shoebox (http://the-shoebox.org/).

Comment: This is an extremely confusing question. Perhaps you could be more descriptive in the future - this question almost looks like a case of abuse due to its ambiguity.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly egregious about it. It might have been nice to explain what shoes is for those who are not sufficiently oriented to the subject matter, but then those people are not likely to answer the question anyway.

Comment: My point is "Do you have documentation on functions in shoe" is too ambiguous. "Do you have documentation on functions available in the Shoe GUI Toolkit" is much more descriptive, and will match up to searches better. If I search "Ruby GUI Toolkits," I should be able to find this post. But I can't.

Comment: dreftymac, 
thanks. 

Jonathan Sampson, excelent sugestion. though I did find your initial comment un-helpfull. This is how we learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
shoes -m
```

in a console (command prompt) window, shoes will run in Help/Manual mode.

In this mode it displays the shoes manual, complete with runnable examples (the manual is a shoes application) This mode has a built-in search feature which jumps straight to the relevant section of the docs and is very handy for reference.

Most of this info is reformatted as html in the [help.shoooes.net](http://help.shoooes.net/) site mentioned above.

As most open source projects go it's well documented. And _why seems to have actually shown restraint in the documentation (he obviously worked out his cartoony madness in the nobody knows shoes manual!).

Comment: added link: http://help.shoooes.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Shoes Help](http://help.shoooes.net/) seems to have all kinds of reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen such thing for Shoes. It seems Why prefers to document his stuff with cartoons and collages.

Have you read [Nobody Knows Shoes](http://hackety.org/press/)?

Comment: It was just too "My first programming book" at first glance, I'll take another look at it.

Comment: True.

But I think the purpose of Shoes is to have an unusually low barrier to entry (like in the old C64 Basic days), allowing kids to start programming and be able to create graphics in a few lines of code. I don't know if there is more to Shoes than being "My first programming framework".

Answer (score 0):

Animation objects inherit from TimerBase (as do Every objects and Timer objects), and as such have the methods draw, remove, start, stop, and toggle.  I don't know too much more... this is from my notes I took while digging through the shoes source.  But those would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no real documentation, as such--you just have to glean it from examples [?]
An attempt at rdoc failed pretty well [just ran rdoc from within the github repo]
http://roger.doachristianturndaily.info/ruby/shoes/doc/ 
you can look into the C code to try to discover them :)